# Computation of uniform limits

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have the following sequences of functions:

$f_n(x)=n^3x^n(1-x)$ on $[0,1/2]$ (conjecture: this converges uniform to $0$)

$f_n(x)=\frac{x}{nx+1}$ on $(0,1)$ (conjecture: also uniform limit to $0$)

$f_n(x)=\frac{nx^2+1}{nx+1}$ on $[1,2]$ (conjecture: pointwise limit to $f(x)=x$)

I think you can use Dini's Theorem in the first case. But how to do this? How to obtain the limits in the other cases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conjectures are true.

For the first problem note that for large $n$ we have
$$
n^{3}x^{n}(1-x) = \frac{n^{3}}{\exp (n\log |x|)}(1-x) < \frac{n^{3}}{n^{4}}(1-x) < \frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $x \in ]0,1/2]$.

For the second problem note that 
$$
\frac{x}{nx+1} < \frac{x}{nx} = \frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n\geq 1$ and all $x \in ]0,1[$.

For the last note that
$$
\bigg| \frac{nx^{2}+1}{nx+1} - x \bigg| = \bigg| \frac{nx^{2}+1-nx^{2}-x}{nx+1} \bigg| = \bigg| \frac{1-x}{nx+1} \bigg| \leq \frac{1}{nx+1} + \frac{x}{nx+1} \to 0
$$
for all $x \in [1,2]$.

Comment: Is the last one also uniform convergent?

Comment: @BlakeMccoy Yes, it is. :)

Comment: Can you use Dini's Theorem here?

Comment: This is another question; if you want to apply it, you have to check if the sequence is monotone (continuity, p.w. convergence, compactness, p.w. limit continuity are plain).